# Update and display updated product prices in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, product

Iam trying to update woocommerce prices programmatically with with CRON.

I'm saving the new price to the _price, _regular_price and _sale_price post meta.

The post meta are correcty saved. But, somehow, the price is not updated.

This is a piece of the code:

```
function save_prices($post_ID){
    $woo_prod = wc_get_product( $post_ID );

    $price = some_function_to_get_the_price( $post_ID ); 


   if($woo_prod->is_type( 'simple' )){

        $woo_prod->update_meta_data( '_regular_price', $price );
        $woo_prod->update_meta_data( '_sale_price', $price );
        $woo_prod->update_meta_data( '_price', $price );

   }

   $woo_prod->save();
}
```

This function saves the post meta correctly, but woocommerce doesn't use these values for the product.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new [CRUD getters and setters methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) introduced with Woocommerce 3 instead:

```
function save_prices($post_ID){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_ID );

    $price = some_function_to_get_the_price( $post_ID ); 

    if($product->is_type( 'simple' )){
        $product->set_regular_price($price);
        $product->set_sale_price($price);
        $product->set_price($price);
    }
    $product->save();
}
```

Now it should work and display the updated prices in front end.

See the [related documentation for available `WC_Product` CRUD methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)